# Google Calendar API on Android access token

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I want to query and add events to the primary calendar of a user that is already logged into the app (with his/her/its' google account).

I have come this far:

```
class CalendarClient {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "TrackTransfer";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    private final String token;

    CalendarClient (String token){
        this.token = token;
    }

    private Credential getCredentials() {
        return new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token);
    }

    void print() throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();
        Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials())
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
        DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Events events = service.events().list("primary")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();
        List<Event> items = events.getItems();
        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No upcoming events found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Upcoming events");
            for (Event event : items) {
                DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
                if (start == null) {
                    start = event.getStart().getDate();
                }
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", event.getSummary(), start);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and I call it like this from an activity where the user is already signed in and the signed in account is represented by `account`.

```
private void writeToCalendar()  {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.d("CAL", "token: " + account.getIdToken());
                CalendarClient c = new CalendarClient(account.getIdToken());
                c.print();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

However, the account.getIdToken() is `Null` even though the user is signed in.
I also tried setting the token to the client-ID that I get for my application in the google developer console, which doesn't work either.

Naturally when the token is `Null` I get an exception stating that the contingent for non-signed in api calles is exceeded.

Accessing the Fitness API just before the call of `writeToCalendar()` wasn't a problem with that account (so it is signed in).

I have looked at various resources, but neither proved helpful. The Google API documentation was about Java and used the credentials obtained from the developer console; however as I want to authenticate using OAuth, this is not the right thing to do (i guess?).
Then I found that one can use `GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token)` but I couldn't figure out what token is used.

How do I obtain the correct token?

**Update**

When requesting scopes for the account to be logged in, it is straight forward with the fitness api:

```
FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build();
GoogleSignInAccount gsa = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions);
```

with a callback that looks something like this:

```
account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
```

However, when requesting a scope for the calendar api is the following correct?

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"))
                .build();
GoogleSignInClient tempClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

Comment: I have to ask, did you enable the api?

Comment: good point, but yes;

Comment: and is the key restricted to a device type?

Comment: if this is not a default setting then no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign in

[sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/)

I also found this, you may need to use oauth before the api gives you an access token:

[auth](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth)

Then I would check to see if its one of the api's you need to enable a billing account for.  It might be.  That does not mean you need to pay...depending on the api google makes you 'enable' billing.  Not sure if the this api is one of those.

[info](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158867?hl=en)

Comment: but how will that help in making the token non Null?

Comment: I updated the answer.  But for sure some of the map api's and maybe this one don't give you access until the billing account is set up [even though it's free]  Its a google thing.

Answer (score 0):

With high probability, that *existing login* does not feature the required oAuth2 [scopes](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth).

Requesting these before already should provide the scopes to be able to access the API.

Comment: Is it correct to request the scopes like in the updated question? or do you have to do it differently when using the google Calendar API?

Answer (score 0):

To use calendar api you need accessToken. In your example instead of it you are using idToken. 
Even if you get idToken and reqest events with it you will get error.

```
code: 401
message: wrong credential
```

In order to get a token you can use one of two the methods: AuthUtils.getToken, GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(). But before these you must request permissions(google sign in + scoppes) so as not to get an error: "permission not granted". (https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth)

AuthUtils.getToken:

```
 @Deprecated
 public static String getToken(Context context, String email, String var2) throws IOException, UserRecoverableAuthException, GoogleAuthException

 public static String getToken(Context var0, Account var1, String var2) throws IOException, UserRecoverableAuthException, GoogleAuthException
```

GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(recommended method https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide):

```
  /**
   * @param transport HTTP transport
   * @param jsonFactory JSON factory
   * @param clientId client identifier issued to the client during the registration process
   * @param clientSecret client secret
   * @param code authorization code generated by the authorization server
   * @param redirectUri redirect URL parameter matching the redirect URL parameter in the
   *        authorization request (see {@link #setRedirectUri(String)}
   */
  public GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory,
      String clientId, String clientSecret, String code, String redirectUri)
```